# PHP duplicate data when looping

Tags: php, loops, foreach, duplicates

I need help.

I have data with commas (`,`). And I want to convert it to `array` or `json`.
But when looping through it, the data in the first and last elements is duplicated.

Data from database on column `additional`. with `NULL` as default.

example:

```
+----+------------+
| id | addtional  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | ada        |
|  2 | NULL       |
|  3 | kursi,meja |
|  4 | NULL       |
+----+------------+
```

then call for looping

```
if( $p->additional !== NULL ) {
    $gmb = explode(',', $p->additional);

    $gmbbb = array();
    foreach ($gmb as $gbr) {
        $gmbbb[] = $gbr;
    }
    $keterangan['i'] = $gmbbb;
}
```

And the final result from `$keterangan` is:

```
Array
(
    [i] => Array
        (
            [0] => ada
        )
)
Array
(
    [i] => Array
        (
            [0] => ada
        )
)
Array
(
    [i] => Array
        (
            [0] => kursi
            [1] => meja
        )
)
Array
(
    [i] => Array
        (
            [0] => kursi
            [1] => meja
        )
)
```

How to stop duplicate if it's `NULL`, I need data from `additional` when it's `NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is different approach for you.Hope this will help you.But i dont know your table name and all.Make the sql query like below:

```
mysql>SELECT addtional FROM table_name WHERE addtional IS NOT NULL;
```